# 400 Bad Request Error when using custom decorator in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I made the following decorator in flask to secure my API:

```
def auth_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        if session.get('user') is None:
            if 'Authorization' not in request.headers:
                return jsonify({'status': 0,'message':'Unauthorized'})
            else:
                try:
                    token = request.headers.get('Authorization')
                    data = jwt.decode(token.split(" ")[1], app.config['SECRET_KEY'],algorithms=['HS256'])
                    return f(*args, **kwargs)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(str(e))
                    return jsonify({'status': 0,'message':'Unauthorized'})
        else:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_function
```

This works fine when it is used on the web when sessions are used and not JWTs but when I use cURL like:

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer mytoken123" -X POST -d '{"phone":"myphonenumber","type":"send"}' http://localhost:5000/api/OTP
```

I get the following response:

```
400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Dec/2018 14:00:30] "POST /api/OTP HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

What is going on here?

Comment: Are you sure it's failing in the decorator itself? What's the function you're applying the decorator to and how? As it stands, when triggering via `cURL` it should just forward the call to the wrapped function...

Comment: @zwer there was some error in the API itself. fixed it